# Haskell: Verifying if a constructor is Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a type

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

I need to verify if the following type constructor Maybe is a Monad

```
instance Monad Maybe where
        return x = Just x
        Nothing >>= f = Just (f (Nothing))
        (Just x) >>= f = f x
```

Please give me some pointers how to do above task.

Thanks

Comment: By the way, the second line `Nothing >>= f = Just (f (Nothing))` looks wrong -- `f` does not take a `Maybe something`, in general.

Comment: "I need to" - so it is homework? Then I'm sure your teacher has already given "some pointers".

Comment: No. This is a special teacher and a free course.
He advises to do google search.

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried your definition?

Answer (score 5):

For that, you have to verify the [monad laws](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads#Monad_Laws). These come in several (equivalent) forms, the closest to Haskell monads being

```
x >>= return     =  x
return x >>= f   =  f x
(x >>= f) >>= g  =  x >>= (\y -> f y >>= g)
```

Start from the first and apply the definitions for `>>=` and `return`. You may wish to proceed by cases: either `x` is `Nothing` or it is `Just a` for some value `a`...